# One file, syntax highlight for multiple filetypes

Tags: vim

When taking notes during lectures, I find myself frequently wanting to highlight a segment of a file, say a 5-line code snippet with syntax for it's respective language, while leaving the syntax highlighting of the rest of the file intact.

I read some of the Vim Tips on it, but they seemed rather messy and more hassle than what I think it's worth.

Are there any smart ways of achieving this, or am barking up the wrong tree by even trying?

Answer (score 2):

Try my [SyntaxRange plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4168). It provides a `:[range]SyntaxInclude {filetype}` command that lets you set up ad-hoc regions. It also offers functions that can automatically detect ranges based on markers in the text.